# Check if div is on page, if not hide button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have button in a global navigation that calls a search dropdown, but the search dropdown isn't present on every page. How can I look for the search dropdown and hide/show the button based on if it's present or not? I'm thinking something like below, but I'm not totally sure of the code.

```
if(search exists) {
    show button
} 
else {
    hide button
}
```

Comment: You can try to use the `.has()` function from jQuery. [Read here](https://api.jquery.com/has/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) property

> The number of elements in the jQuery object.

```
if($('validSelector').length) {
   //show button
} 
else {
   //hide button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an id to your search dropdown and check if a div with that id is exist on the page. Like:

```
<div id="mydropdown"></div>

<script>
if(document.getElementById('mydropdown'))
console.log("do some stuff");
else console.log("do nothing");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

Checking for [length](https://api.jquery.com/length/) of selected result

> Description: The number of elements in the jQuery object.

```
if($(YOUR_SEARCH_DROPDOWN_SELECTOR).length) { //or $(YOUR_SEARCH_DROPDOWN_SELECTOR).size()
     $(BUTTON_SELECTOR).show();
} 
else {
     $(BUTTON_SELECTOR).hide();
}
```